# how to write a path using regexp

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, object

So i need to figure out how to write the following path into regexp

> /private/toolbox/*

I'm not sure how to do it because of the *

I have add the following 2 paths with no problem

> /private/healthcheck
>
> /private/datadog/dashboards

```
        .type(RegExp)).default([/^\/private\/metrics/, /^\/private\/datadog\/dashboards/,/^\/private\/healthcheck/, /^\/alive.txt/]),
```

Comment: Are you matching the character `*` literally, or does the asterisk represent a wildcard?

Comment: `*` is meant to be a wildcard

Comment: Can't you use a single regex for all those paths ? `^/(?:private/(?:toolbox/\*|metrics/|datadog/dashboards/|healthcheck/)|alive\.txt)` or quoted `/^\/(?:private\/(?:toolbox\/\*|metrics\/|datadog\/dashboards\/|healthcheck\/)|alive\.txt)/`

Comment: In general, you should be able to replace Windows style path wildcard `*` with `.*` in a regex and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:\/private\/toolbox\/)(.+)` ought to match your route path, capturing the wildcard as the first group:

```
const path  = '/private/toolbox/whichever';
const match = path.match(/(?:\/private\/toolbox\/)(.+)/);

console.log(match);
```

I cannot speak to that RegExp's performance, however.